# Supervisord and stdout/stderr

Tags: supervisord

For a program configuration block in Supervisord, is it necessary to set stderr_logfile if redirect_stderr is true?

```
stderror_logfile=/path/to/logfile/stderr.log
stdout_logfile=/path/to/logfile/stdout.log
redirect_stderr=true
```

Since redirect_stderr is true, this should mean that stderr.log will be empty, and the combination of stderr and stdout streams will show up in sdtout.log.  Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Quoting Supervisord configuration file documentation :

> `redirect_stderr`
> If true, cause the process’ stderr output to be sent back to supervisord on its stdout file descriptor (in UNIX shell terms, this is the equivalent of executing `/the/program 2>&1`).
>
> `stderr_logfile`
> Put process stderr output in this file unless redirect_stderr is true.

Then yes, both `stderr` and `stdout` will appear in `stdout.log`, and `stderr.log` will remain empty.

Comment: Thx, seemed like that's what the docs meant, but wanted to double check.